# Override back button on xamarin android app

Tags: android, .net, xamarin

I am building an application using Xamarin and it's Android Player for Android. Whenever I hit the back button it seems to back out of the application completely. I want to be able to change this default to go back to the previous page in my app. How do I override the back button behavior?

Comment: When navigating are you opening new activities or new fragments?

Comment: Its not a fragment so I presume it would be an activitie this is how I am changing pages Thanks for your help. protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);
          
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Login);
            Button btnLogin = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnLogin);
            btnLogin.Click += new EventHandler(Login1);
        }

        private void Login1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);         

        }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the previous answer is correct, you can trap the hardware back button and do whatever you want with it. But I want to make sure you understand why this is happening. Android handles the hardware back button for you, and most of the time, letting Android handle it will work, it knows what to do.

But in your case, you're not actually navigating at all. Your click handler is removing one layout file and replacing it with another. This is the equivalent of showing/hiding a div in web development. You're not actually changing the screen(page).

Because of this, when you hit the back button, you're still on the first (and only) screen in your app, so the OS does the only thing it knows to do, it closes the app.

If you want to continue with the paradigm of showing/hiding layouts in lieu of actually navigating, I would trap the hardware back button and re-swap your layout files.

```
public override bool OnKeyDown(Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
{
    if (keyCode == Keycode.Back) {
       SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Login)
       return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

But the true solution that I would recommend would be to read up on how to truly navigate in Xamarin Android. Swapping your layout files and putting all the logic for your entire app in one Activity will be very hard to maintain.

Comment: Thats perfect and thanks for the advice I mainly needed this for the current version of my app for a deadline, I will be sure to follow your advice and fix it up afterwards thanks for the temporary hack around my issue its exactly what was required :)

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the `OnKeyDown` and decide whether to allow the Back button to ripple up the event chain or not:

```
public override bool OnKeyDown(Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
{
    if (keyCode == Keycode.Back) {
       Toast.MakeText (this, "Back button blocked", ToastLength.Short).Show ();
       return false;
    }
    Toast.MakeText (this, "Button press allowed", ToastLength.Short).Show ();
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can handle that in the OnBackPressed() event.